# how to deal with microsoft xpath namespace "bug"?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

When processing xmlDocument with xPath using, for example, SelectNodes, there's a behavior in documents, which contain any namespace declarations, which I  consider a bug:

If an xml document contains any namespaces declarations (e g xmlns=..... or something similar), the xquerry will always come out empty.

A lazy-ass way of dealing with this is to run following code on the xml text before loading it into the XmlDocumennt:

```
pg = Regex.Replace(pg, @"xmlns\s*\=\s*""[^""]*""", "");
pg = Regex.Replace(pg, @"xmlns\s*\=\s*'[^']*'", "");
```

We can also use XmlNamespaceManager to pall namespace information into the xpath call. I find both approaches cumbersome (I usually don't know the namespaces of the documents that the software will be working with, and, also, I don't really care).

Is there an easy to use way to disable this behavior of Microsoft's XPath parser, which also "feels" right?

Comment: It's not a bug, it is correct behavior. Namespaces in XML are relevant.

Comment: Learn to understand namespaces before you dismiss them.

Comment: ok. So could you please tell me a good way to parse a document with arbitrary namespaces, which I can't and don't know in advance?

Comment: Well you will need to explain what you want to achieve, telling us you don't care about namespaces does not explain us what you want to achieve in case there are namespace present. If you want to select elements solely based on their local name and ignore the namespaces then you can of course write e.g. `//*[local-name() = 'foo']` to select all elements with local name `foo` independent of their namespace. Or move to third party XQuery 1.0 or XPath 2.0 implementations where you can use `//*:foo` to achieve the same.

Answer (score 4):

If you really don't care about the namespaces then I'd say stripping them from the XML would seem to feel right.  I'd not recommend such an approach in a production environment though, where you probably should care about namespaces.

Comment: ok. So could you please tell me a good way to parse a document with arbitrary namespaces, which I can't and don't know in advance?

Comment: It depends what you want to do with the data. Remember, not knowing the namespace in advance is just the same as not knowing the local name in advance. What information can you extract from an element whose name is not known in advance?